# WebClient.DownloadString(url) when this url returns a 404 page, how can i skip this?

Tags: c#, http-status-code-404, webclient

I'm using WebClient.DownloadString(url) to download a web page, when a url a 404 web page it stops and doesn't work anymore.
I want to skip these pages when I got this fault.

if the url is 404 page, it doesn't start to download. so i can't parse the undownloaded data...

Comment: Please don't prefix your titles with "C#" and such. That's what the tags are for.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You will have to catch the Exception and test for a 404:

```
try
{
    string myString;
    using (WebClient wc = new WebClient())
        myString= wc.DownloadString("http://foo.com");

}
catch (WebException ex)
{
    if (ex.Status == WebExceptionStatus.ProtocolError && ex.Response != null)
    {
        var resp = (HttpWebResponse)ex.Response;
        if (resp.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.NotFound) // HTTP 404
        {
            //the page was not found, continue with next in the for loop
            continue;
        }
    }
    //throw any other exception - this should not occur
    throw;
}
```

Comment: I have tried this answer in my project. but it's crashing at throw with the 404. error. Do I just remove throw? or is there a more elegant way of approaching it.

Answer (score 0):

You can put your code in a `Try...Catch` block and catch a [WebException](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webexception.aspx). If you want more control on how to handle specific errors, you can use the WebException's `Status` property which returns a [WebExceptionStatus](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webexceptionstatus.aspx) enumeration.