# WebClient throws exception on 404

Tags: c#, .net, webclient

I have stumbled across an insane behavior of WebClient where it throws WebException on 404 code.

This behavior is wrong because the 404 code can be returned with content data like in the case of Facebook: `https://graph.facebook.com/sadfsa.dsadsasadsa`

So this code throws an exception

```
 var json = webClient.DownloadString("https://graph.facebook.com/sadfsa.dsadsasadsa");
```

How do I read the json returned by 404 Facebook?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8915785/webclient-downloadstringurl-when-this-url-returns-a-404-page-how-can-i-skip-t

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think that WebClient has insane behavior. Try to catch `WebException` and read `webException.Response.GetResponseStream`

See a similar question: [C# WebException how to get whole response with a body?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11828843/c-sharp-webexception-how-to-get-whole-response-with-a-body)

Comment: It's too bad that you don't think that WebClient has insane behavior

Comment: a http status code other than 200 is not an exceptional state.