# Something like HttpClient.TryDownload

Tags: .net

I would like to implement something that will not throw an exception when HTTP status code is 404. Can I use `System.Web.WebRequest` class or must use lower APIs? (I cannot send HTTP HEAD request first, because some servers ignores them.)

Comment: catching and handling the error is out of discussion? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8915785/webclient-downloadstringurl-when-this-url-returns-a-404-page-how-can-i-skip-t

Comment: Why dont you try? It is hardly more than a few lines of code.

Comment: When I debug my code, I don't want be interrupted everytime someone messed up an URL. It would be brilliant also be able to stop downloading data when I detect content-type I'm not interested in. But it looks like implementation on socket level and that's something I would like to avoid.

Comment: That's basically the same logic like int.TryParse or Uri.TryCreate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is another API. It is *System.Net.Http.HttpClient*. For .NET lower than 4.5 the *System.Net.Http* NuGet package is required.