# Check if folder on web exists or not

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2012

I'm creating desktop aplication and when I write a username in `TextBox1` and on `Button1.Click` event it should check does folder on web exists.
As far I've tried this:

```
 username = Me.TextBox1.Text
 password = Me.TextBox2.Text

        Dim dir As Boolean = IO.Directory.Exists("http://www.mywebsite.com/" + username)
        If dir = true Then
            Dim response As String = web.DownloadString("http://www.mywebsite.com/" + username + "/Password.txt")
            If response.Contains(password) Then
                MsgBox("You've logged in succesfully", MsgBoxStyle.Information)
                Exit Sub
            Else
                MsgBox("Password is incorect!")
            End If
        Else
            MsgBox("Username is wrong, try again!")
        End If
```

First problem is that my boolean is giving FALSE as answer (directory exists for sure and all permissions are granted to see folder). I tried to solve that with setting `dir = false` and after that I go into first IF (but that's not what I want, since it should be TRUE, not FALSE)
There we come to second problem, in this line:  `Dim response As String=web.DownloadString("http://www.mywebsite.com/" + username + "/Password.txt")` I get this error message: `The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found.`
Anyone more experienced with this kind of things who can help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`IO.Directory.Exists` will not work in this case. That method only works to check for a folder on a disk somewhere (locally or network) ; you can't use it to check for the existence of a resource over HTTP. (i.e a URI)

- But even if it did work this way, it's actually pointless to call it before attempting to download - the method `DownloadString` will throw an exception if something goes wrong - as you have seen, in this case it's telling you *404 Not Found* which means "This resource does not exist as far as you are concerned". **
- So you should `try/catch` the operation, you need to catch exceptions of type `WebException`, cast its `Response` member to HttpWebException, and check the `StatusCode` property.
  An good example (albeit in C#) is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8915785/webclient-downloadstringurl-when-this-url-returns-a-404-page-how-can-i-skip-t)

** I say "as far as you are concerned" because for all you know, the resource may very well exist on the server, but it has decided to hide it from you because you do not have access to it, etc, and the developer of that site decided to return 404 in this case instead of 401 Unauthorised. The point being that from your point of view, the resource is not available.

### Update:

here is the code from the answer I linked to, translated via [this online tool](http://www.developerfusion.com/tools/convert/csharp-to-vb/) because my VB is dodgy enough :). This code runs just fine for me in LinqPad, and produces the output "*testlozinka*"

```
Sub Main
Try
    Dim myString As String
    Using wc As New WebClient()
        myString = wc.DownloadString("http://dota2world.org/HDS/Klijenti/TestKlijent/password.txt")
        Console.WriteLine(myString)
    End Using
Catch ex As WebException
 Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString())
    If ex.Status = WebExceptionStatus.ProtocolError AndAlso ex.Response IsNot Nothing Then
        Dim resp = DirectCast(ex.Response, HttpWebResponse)
        If resp.StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.NotFound Then
            ' HTTP 404
            'the page was not found, continue with next in the for loop
            Console.WriteLine("Page not found")
        End If
    End If
    'throw any other exception - this should not occur
    Throw
End Try
End Sub
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Can you please 'translate' me that answer from link you gave me into Vb.net? I am not really good with C#. By the way, thank you for your answer, I figured out that IO.Directory.Exists doesn't even make sence in this kind of situation.

Comment: I've changed some things and in this way I've done this should work, but still I get a message about 404 error.  I am owner of host and domain where I uploaded and opened folders and I changed permission to 7 7 7 which means this should work without any problem.

Comment: See updated answer for translated code. Re the 404 - if you open this URL in a browser, can you access the file?

Comment: I've tried with your method still get the same error message.
I can open my URL you can check [HERE](http://dota2world.org/HDS/Klijenti/TestKlijent/password.txt) as you can see I can read a string from that link

Comment: Hmm. See updated answer. I ran the code in LinqPad and it worked just fine.

Comment: Wierd, this one works, but right when I change it to `myString = wc.DownloadString("http://www.dota2world.org/HDS/Klijenti/" + Me.TextBox1.Text + "/Password.txt")` it doesn't work anymore and gives the same message again, I double checked did I wrote it exactly as it is and I did. But yet, it leaves me a problem of how to check does Directory exists or not...

Comment: ...what are you entering in the textbox - are you *sure* you don't have a leading/trailing space or an extra "/" in there?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/47100/discussion-between-nidzaaaa-and-stephen-byrne)  if you're free of course

Comment: Sorry, but I'm actually heading out the door right this minute :( I am sure it's something simple in your textbox, the network related code is working.

Comment: Ok, thank you for your help anyway, I hope I will solve this problem soon since I'm already realy tired of trying.

Comment: Just want to tell you that I did it afterall. Now it works all great, you were right, it was just a minor typing mistake caused by high level if tiredness. Thank you once again.

Comment: Excellent, glad you got it sorted.